# Xamrin Forms issue with Datanotations

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, ef-core-2.0

I have a Web API which returns JSON that is deserialized into object. I am using Xamrin forms.

In my standard web client dll I have the following:

```
 public class xxxWc : IHttpService
 {
     readonly IJsonConverter jsonConverter;
     public xxxWc()
     {}

     public FuelWc(IJsonConverter jsonConverter)
     {
         this.jsonConverter = jsonConverter;
     }

     public async Task<T> Get<T>(string url)
     {
         using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
         {
             var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
             var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

             return jsonConverter.Deserialize<T>(json);
         }
     }
```

Then I can consume the list as follows:

```
 public class xxxApiClient : IApi
 {
     readonly string url = "http://localhost:81/api ";
     readonly IHttpService httpService;

     public xxxApiClient(IHttpService httpService)
     {
         this.httpService = httpService;
     }

     public Task<List<JobsList>> GetJobs() => 
         httpService.Get<List<JobsList>>($"{url}JobsLists");
    }
```

I am trying not to have to version of models so I want to reference my models contained in my Data Model Layer in my Xamarin Forms layer.

So, in my views I use

```
using xxxxx;
using xxxxx.Interface;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace xxxxxCallMangmentApp.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class JobsPage : ContentPage
    {
        IApi api;
        public JobsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            SetItemSource();
        }

        private async void SetItemSource()
        {
            JobListingsListView.ItemsSource = await api.GetJobs();
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is, when I deploy to Xamarin Live Player the data annotations doesn't work and crashes. How should I deal with this situation as I need the classes to deserialize the json back into .Net ojbects?

In case you wonder, I am using XXX to hide my company's namespaces.

**Edit 1**

It appears that this would be a known issue with Xamarin Forms.
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2692

They Just logged it as a bug
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/projects/3#card-9713971